# Linear combination of homogenous polynomials vanishes on sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $P,Q,R:\mathbb{R}^{m+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be three homogenous polynomials of degree $2$. If $P,Q,R$ are not constant on $\mathbb{S}^m$, but
$$
c_1 + c_2 P + c_3 Q + c_4 PQ + c_5 P^2 Q + c_6 R = 0, \text{ on } \mathbb{S}^m
$$
where $c_i$, $i = 1,2, \ldots 6$ are real constants.
Can we say something about these constants?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider $m=1$, and $P(x, y)=x^2$, $Q(x, y)=x^2(x^2+y^2)$ and $R(x, y)$ aribtrary. Here $P-Q=0$ on $S^1$, with nonzero constants. (Similar examples with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \neq 0$ can be constructed using that $(x^2+y^2-1)^2=0$ on $S^1$.)

Comment: What if we add the condition for $P,Q,R$ to preserve the degree on the sphere? I mean, $x^2(x^2+y^2) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$.